# How to use parameterized region in Prism?

Tags: prism, region

My shell has toolbar, navigation and main regions. While some menu item (foo) in toolbar selected, the navigation should be reloaded with parameter foo; and the main region should be reset with the parameter. How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [RegionContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458944.aspx)